# alamofire json parsing swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3, xcode8, alamofire

I'm new to swift. I'm trying to parse data from URL in swift 3. I'm trying with this code:

```
Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").responseJSON { response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
```

And I got JSON as below:

```
JSON: (
    {
    completed = 0;
    id = 1;
    title = "delectus aut autem";
    userId = 1;
},
    {
    completed = 0;
    id = 2;
    title = "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui";
    userId = 1;
})
```

Anyone can help me how to parse all of this value to dictionary or array and present it in a table view in swift 3?

Here is code for implement my tableview

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return object.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return object.property.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = property.[indexPath]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Show you code of `tableView`

Comment: just a simple table view. that have  4 row in 1 section to show value. thank if you help me.

Comment: Then add that code inside your question also what information you want to show with TableCell?

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

Create Model like this way

```
class YourData: NSObject {

    var completed: Bool
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var userId: String


    init(dict: NSDictionary) {
        completed = dict["completed"] as? Bool ?? false
        id = dict["id"] as? String ?? ""
        title = dict["title"] as? String ?? ""
        userId = dict["userId"] as? String ?? ""
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Try this for parse.

```
let arrayData : [YourData]  = []

if let JSON = response.result.value as? [Dictionary] {
    for dict in JSON {
        let data = YourData(dict: dict)
        arrayData.append(data)
    }
}
```

Now you can use `arrayData` in `tableview`

Comment: At line 3: "for dict in Json", got error : Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'sequence'

Comment: **Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift!** You throw away the strong type information.

Comment: your answer alway get error! You don't test it before answer?